# Install node module from own gitlab server

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab

I'd like to install node modules from our gitlab server. This is a link to a repository:

> http://ABCD-GITLAB/myGroup/myNodeModule.git

According to the [npm install guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) the install command should be this:

```
gitlabUser: me
myProject: myNodeModule
npm install gitlab:mygitlabuser/myproject
```

I have no idea how to reference my

- gitlab server url
- group
- project
- account name

I tried some commands but all failed:

```
npm install gitlab:ABCD-GITLAB:me/myproject
npm install gitlab:ABCD-GITLAB:me/myproject.git
npm install gitlab:http://ABCD-GITLAB:me/myproject
npm install gitlab:http://ABCD-GITLAB:me/myproject.git
npm install gitlab:http://ABCD-GITLAB:me/myGroup/myproject
npm install gitlab:http://ABCD-GITLAB:me/myGroup/myproject.git
npm install gitlab:http://ABCD-GITLAB:me/myGroup/myproject.git
```

What is the correct way to reference a npm dependency, a clear structure would be great like

```
npm install gitlab:<serverUrl/>:<username/>/<groupname/>/<projectname/><gitsuffix>.git
```

Comment: I suppose that instead of "`gitlab:`" you probably should use "`git:`".

Comment: complete gitlab-server url (http://..), only the url (ABCD-GITLAB), where to define the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try one of these:

```
npm install git+ssh://git@ABCD-GITLAB:myGroup/myNodeModule.git
npm install git+https://git@ABCD-GITLAB/myGroup/myNodeModule.git
npm install git://ABCD-GITLAB/myGroup/myNodeModule.git
```

You may need to change `git` to your username and you can add `#v1.0.27` or something like that at the end for a specific version or tag:

```
npm install git://ABCD-GITLAB/myGroup/myNodeModule.git#v1.0.27
```

You can also install from a tarball:

```
npm install https://ABCD-GITLAB:myGroup/myNodeModule/repository/archive.tar.gz
```

You can add `?ref=master` to the end of the tarball URL for the branch.

Comment: "npm install git://ABCD-GITLAB/myGroup/myNodeModule.git" worked for me. unfortunately --save didn't. The npm install docu is very confusing.