# Read external credentials in package.json

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, npm

I need to have my common npm module as git dependency and use it in many modules. 
I'm trying to use access token for authorize in git. Bit I don't want to store the token in package.json (at least, it's hard to change it in few modules if it change).

Can I do something like this:

**package.json**

```
... 
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "read-credentials.sh" 
}
...
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-module": "git+https://$$$token-from-variable$$$:x-oauth-basic@some-repo-url"
    ...
}
```

I know about options with private npm modules or make ssh keys for git access, but it isn't a good fit for me. The main point of the question is to figure out if there is a way to set variables from some preinstall script (where I can have access to access tokens) and use them in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

You can have [private modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) on npm. It costs $7/month and is created for exactly the use case that you have here.

If you don't want to do that for some reason, then you can rely on [git-specific environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) to resolve your dependencies. For example if you use `git+ssh://git@SERVER:USER/MODULE.git` as a dependency then npm will try to get it with git using the default credentials used by git (which in turn uses the credentials used by ssh). You can even change `GIT_SSH` environment variable to completely control the SSH session however you want.

For more options see [Install node module from own gitlab server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656875/install-node-module-from-own-gitlab-server/40657419#40657419).

Comment: Sorry, I updated question. Private modules, environment variables or ssh keys aren't good solution for me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: This answer was written before this was added to the question: "I know about options with private npm modules or make ssh keys for git access, but it doesn't good fit for me."

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, there is no way to create such kind of variables. 
My solution for my problem:

1. Creating other module, which can take a token from external place and which I can put in public git or npm repo.
2. Add this module in dependency.
3. Call it in postinstall script.
4. Get token, build url and install my private-git-module from JS  using npm.commands.install.